# Disable indent selection by tab

Tags: visual-studio-2012, indent

When I select text in Visual Studio (C++ if it matters) and hit the tab key, instead of replacing the selected text with a tab, it instead indents the selected code. I really want to disable this "feature", as I have a different shortcut for doing the same thing but with modifier keys (ALT + NUMPAD_PLUS).

I have tried scouring VS's options and Google without luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I beleive this is a baked in feature of most code-editors as there are frequent times you want to increase/decrease the indent level of code. You can use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> or even <kbd>Space bar</kbd> to remove the selection.